# Build error in Xcode on Unity3d project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm building with IL2CPP scripting backend. The strange thing is a did a few build already and it worked but now I started getting this error in Xcode :

> fatal error: error in backend IO failure on output stream.
>       Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

I already tried reverting the changes I made on the project back to a state were it did build correctly and I still get the same error.

Comment: I stumbled upon this error, when I had *8 MB* space left on my startup disk, and Xcode wasn't able to produce a build. That's why it was giving IO error.

Answer (score 0):

Project Settings > Under "Targets", select your project > Build Phases > open "Compile Sources" and "Copy Bundle Resources". Check if any files are listed in red color. If so , just delete it. Then clean and run.

Worked for me